# How convert PST Unix timestamp to UTC?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetimeoffset

How convert PST Unix timestamp to UTC and then to any custom time zone (GMT+2, ...) ? 
Please provide solution in javascript or nodejs lib ([momentjs](http://momentjs.com/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix timestamps are automatically in GMT, since they are defined as `number of seconds since 00:00 on 1st January 1970 GMT`. You can create a date object from a timestamp via `new Date(timestamp)` and you can then use [the Date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to format it. Simple math can be used to move between time zones by simply subtracting the number of hours difference.

Comment: I have timestamp in Pacific timezone. It can be PST or PDT. How to know what value I need to subtract ?

Comment: "Simple math can be used to move between time zones by simply subtracting the number of hours difference." => not that simple, if you want to account for DST. Same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615828/how-to-use-timezone-offset-in-nodejs), but expressed better.