# How to use timezone offset in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone

I need the next flow:

```
var a = new Date(1337324400000, 'Europe/Amsterdam'); //+2h
console.log(a); // for example 12:00 Mon ...
a.setTimeZone('Europe/Kiev'); //+3h
console.log(a); // 13:00 Mon ...
```

Is there such possibility in nodejs utils api ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [node-time](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-time), as follows:

```
var time = require('time');

var a = new time.Date(1337324400000);

a.setTimezone('Europe/Amsterdam');
console.log(a.toString()); // Fri May 18 2012 09:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
a.setTimezone('Europe/Kiev');
console.log(a.toString()); // Fri May 18 2012 10:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

Comment: Interesting solution but it does change the current process timezone. Not acceptable for me.

Comment: @Stefan, set the `process.env.TZ` to some value such as `America/New_York` or `America/Chicago` and watch the timezones change.

Comment: node-time is not a good option if you deploy on Azure, as we do. You will have problems compiling the bridge ... A better option is timezone-js as that is pure js. It also performs a lot better.

Comment: @oligofren Then shouldn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: eh, Eldar did that in his updated answer. I just commented on this since I went down this route and lost a lot of time, since I was oblivious to the whole cross-compiling madness that awaited when I used node-time :-D

Comment: @weisjohn, setting process.env.TZ from within a running node process will give dangerously wrong results, because libc will already have initialized. Instead it needs to be set before the process starts.

Comment: Node-time doesn't work on Node 15. Moment-timezone solution is better I believe

Answer (score 17):

Moment.js now has **[Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)**

**Install**:

```
npm install --save moment-timezone
```

**Use**:

```
var Moment = require('moment-timezone');
Moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').format();
```

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE:
there is another one now:) https://github.com/mde/timezone-js

> A timezone-enabled, drop-in replacement for the stock JavaScript Date.
>   The timezoneJS.Date object is API-compatible with JS Date, with the
>   same getter and setter methods -- it should work fine in any code that
>   works with normal JavaScript Dates.

---

no there is not

But you can use **moment.js** to make it easier http://momentjs.com/docs/

You still need to know each offset so you will need mapping like `{"Europe/Amsterdam":2,"Europe/Kiev":3}`

Comment: Does it mean I need to create this file with offsets and also calculate daylight saving time ?

Comment: yes you will need to do it by yourself, as far as I know there is no out of the box solution.

Comment: There's one, it's called node-time, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

See Timezone package in npm. It has everything needed built in and is pure JS and seems to be the best timezone handling library available.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone

http://bigeasy.github.io/timezone/

```
var tz = require('timezone/loaded'),
    equal = require('assert').equal,
    utc;

// Get POSIX time in UTC. 
utc = tz('2012-01-01');

// Convert UTC time to local time in a localize language. 
equal(tz(utc, '%c', 'fr_FR', 'America/Montreal'),
      'sam. 31 déc. 2011 19:00:00 EST');
```

> - Timezone is a MicroJS library in pure JavaScript with no dependencies that provides timezone aware date math and date formatting.
> - Timezone uses the IANA Database to determine the correct wall clock time anywhere in the world for any time since the dawn of standardized time.
> - Timezone formats dates with a full implementation of strftime formats, including the GNU date extensions.
> - Timezone represents time in POSIX time and local time using RFC 3999 date strings.
> - Timezone is a full featured standards based time library in pure JavaScript for under 3K minified and gzipped.

Answer (score 0):

Use [moment-timezone.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/) it's a best option to parse, validate & change times over different timezones.