# node.js time module timezone list

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to googling for passing in acceptable parameters for setting up cronJobs based on a users timeZone. Im using a cronJob module which can be found here.

https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

The problem is I need to pass different timeZones but I can't seem to find the acceptable parameters and format for the different timezones. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. For anyone encountering a similar problem here is a reference list by time zone acceptable for node.js. I believe its standard OS time zone stuff.

http://home.tiscali.nl/~t876506/TZworld.html

Comment: @Deans Door: dead link

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the time to a common timezone before registering it with node-cron.

Here's a conversion example from another question.

From [How to use timezone offset in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615828/how-to-use-timezone-offset-in-nodejs) :

```
var time = require('time');

var a = new time.Date(1337324400000);

a.setTimezone('Europe/Amsterdam');
console.log(a.toString()); // Fri May 18 2012 09:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
a.setTimezone('Europe/Kiev');
console.log(a.toString()); // Fri May 18 2012 10:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

Comment: I thought of that but I need to fire off multiple cron scripts for the diffrent timezones at diffrent times. For example I want the cron script to execute 8:00pm local time for all timezones. If I were to set the script for 8:00pm EST then it will fire off at 5:00pm pacific which is not what I want.