# Create a Date object with CET timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

To create Date object in UTC, we would write

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2012,02,30));
```

Without Date.UTC, it takes the `locale` and creates the `Date` object. If I have to create a Date object for `CET` running the program in some part of the world, how would I do it?

Comment: Is `cet` the `central european time`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't create a JavaScript `Date` object "in" any specific timezone. JavaScript `Date` objects always work from a milliseconds-since-the-Epoch UTC value. They have methods that apply the local timezone offset and rules (`getHours` as opposed to `getUTCHours`), but only the local timezone. You can't *set* the timezone the `Date` object uses for its "local" methods.

What you're doing with `Date.UTC` (correctly, other than the leading `0` on `02`) is just initializing the object with the appropriate milliseconds-since-the-Epoch value for that date/time (March 30th at midnight) in UTC, whereas `new Date(2012, 2, 30)` would have interpreted it as March 30th at midnight local time. There is *no* difference in the `Date` object other than the datetime it was initialized with.

If you need a timezone other than local, all you can do is use the UTC version of `Date`'s functions and apply your own offset and rules for the timezone you want to use, which is non-trivial. (The offset is trivial; the rules tend not to be.)

If you go looking, you can find Node modules that handle timezones for you. A quick search for "node timezone" just now gave me [`timezone`](https://npmjs.org/package/timezone) as the first hit. It also gave me links to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615828/how-to-use-timezone-offset-in-nodejs), [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083410/how-to-set-default-timezone-in-node-js), and [this list of timezone modules for Node](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/timezone).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I used the following code       `require('timezone-js');
        var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('2012, 06, 8, 11, 55, 4','Europe/Amsterdam');` and I get the following error `ReferenceError: timezoneJS is not defined`. I ran `npm install timezone-js` before executing the script

Comment: @NandishA: I'm glad this helped. As for the issue with `timezone-js`, that would be an unrelated question. If you can't figure it out from the `timezone-js` and Node docs, post a new question about it. (I don't think you want those numbers in the first argument to be in a string, but of course that's not why you're getting that error.)

Comment: Thanks, I have created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867990/using-timezone-js-in-nodejs-program

Answer (score 3):

```
function getCETorCESTDate() {
    var localDate = new Date();
    var utcOffset = localDate.getTimezoneOffset();
    var cetOffset = utcOffset + 60;
    var cestOffset = utcOffset + 120;
    var cetOffsetInMilliseconds = cetOffset * 60 * 1000;
    var cestOffsetInMilliseconds = cestOffset * 60 * 1000;

    var cestDateStart = new Date();
    var cestDateFinish = new Date();
    var localDateTime = localDate.getTime();
    var cestDateStartTime;
    var cestDateFinishTime;
    var result;

    cestDateStart.setTime(Date.parse('29 March ' + localDate.getFullYear() + ' 02:00:00 GMT+0100'));
    cestDateFinish.setTime(Date.parse('25 October ' + localDate.getFullYear() + ' 03:00:00 GMT+0200'));

    cestDateStartTime = cestDateStart.getTime();
    cestDateFinishTime = cestDateFinish.getTime();

    if(localDateTime >= cestDateStartTime && localDateTime <= cestDateFinishTime) {
        result = new Date(localDateTime + cestOffsetInMilliseconds);
    } else {
        result = new Date(localDateTime + cetOffsetInMilliseconds);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This would always result in UTC+1.  But isn't CET either UTC+1 in winter or UTC+2 in summer?

Comment: Date object have a getMonth and getDay methods, and you can calculate it. I think this is no problem.

Comment: @MobyDisk, I edit my code for detect clock transitions beetwen CET and CSET. Enjoy! Thank you for you comment, in first time, I didn't thought through this point.

Comment: @SergeyKrivtsov 
cestDateStart.setTime(Date.parse('29 March ' + localDate.getFullYear() + ' 02:00:00 GMT+0100'));
    cestDateFinish.setTime(Date.parse('25 October ' + localDate.getFullYear() + ' 03:00:00 GMT+0200'));

Can you please explain this line?

Comment: @SergeyKrivtsov As per docs they just mentioned '02:00 am on the last Sunday of March until 03:00 am on the last Sunday of October.'  but how you gave here specific dates like 29th march and 25th October. Can u plz explain?

Comment: @Manush Do you understand now, which you asked above comment?