# Using timezone-js in nodejs program

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the code that I wrote to use `timezone-js` module to create `Date` object for a specific timezone

```
require('timezone-js');
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('2012, 06, 8, 11, 55, 4','Europe/Amsterdam');
```

I ran `npm install timezone-js` and installed the module.

However , when I run the program, I get the following error

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('2012, 06, 8, 11, 55, 4','Europe/Amsterdam');
             ^
ReferenceError: timezoneJS is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nandish/Documents/MI-Airlines/mi.airline-sync/lib/nodeTest.js:47:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `require`, you assign the result to a variable, and then use that variable. So:

```
var timezoneJS = require('timezone-js');
```

Amongst other things, this means that you can use whatever name you want, for instance:

```
var ts = require('timezone-js');
var dt = new ts.Date(2013, 0, 1);
```

---

Side note: Be sure to read about [the setup requirements](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js#setup) for `timezone-js` if you're going to use it. It needs zone files, which it will try to load dynamically if you don't supply them. The version I tried out has bugs detecting what transport is available, FWIW (it tries to read a global symbol it doesn't know is defined, which throws an exception, rather than using `typeof thesymbol` which doesn't).

If you proactive grab the timezone files as described in that link, and they're in the relative path `tz` from where you're running your script, this works:

```
var timezoneJS = require("timezone-js");
var fs = require('fs');

// Give timezoneJS a transport for loading local timezone files.
// This code is extracted from https://github.com/mde/timezone-js/blob/master/spec/test-utils.js
timezoneJS.timezone.transport = function (opts) {
  // No success handler, what's the point?
  if (opts.async) {
    if (typeof opts.success !== 'function') return;
    opts.error = opts.error || console.error;
    return fs.readFile(opts.url, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      return err ? opts.error(err) : opts.success(data);
    });
  }
  return fs.readFileSync(opts.url, 'utf8');
};

// Init timezones
timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = 'tz'; // <== If you put the files elsewhere, change this
timezoneJS.timezone.init();

// Use it to get a date in Central European Time
var d = new timezoneJS.Date(2013, 7, 1, 'CET');
console.log(d.toString());      // "Local" time for the date instance (CET)
console.log(d.toUTCString());   // UTC
```

...or of course you can use a transport that uses HTTP to load them. I'm surprised the `npm-`-packaged version of `timezone-js` doesn't default to some file-based transport rather than looking for libraries (with the broken check).