# Graph is not plotting when i am passing date which i am converting to different timezone in highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts, linegraph

I have a data set like this

```
temperature,Timezone
45,2019-08-01 12:34:34 CEST+0200
90,2019-08-01 12:34:35 CEST+0200
25,2019-08-01 12:34:36 CEST+0200
3,2019-08-01 12:34:37 CEST+0200
98,2019-08-01 12:34:38 CEST+0200
32,2019-08-01 12:34:39 CEST+0200
96,2019-08-01 12:34:40 CEST+0200
55,2019-08-01 12:34:41 CEST+0200
57,2019-08-01 12:34:42 CEST+0200
20,2019-08-01 12:34:44 CEST+0200
41,2019-08-01 12:34:45 CEST+0200
29,2019-08-01 12:34:46 CEST+0200
48,2019-08-01 12:34:47 CEST+0200
56,2019-08-01 12:34:48 CEST+0200
56,2019-08-01 12:34:49 CEST+0200
```

This is the data which is in the csv and when i convert this data to `json` by angular package so it will convert the `Timezone` values to `string` and that's why when these values are passing to `Highcarts` series data so graph`(Highcarts line graph)` is not plotting. Actually this time is converted in specific timezone so that's why i want to show the time exactly in the csv. So how can i achieve this?

Comment: Highcharts uses time in milliseconds. Convert all your times to milliseconds since 1970 and it should work. More information here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes

Comment: @ewolden how can i convert my all times into milliseconds since 1970 in specific timezone?  because the time which is in my csv is in `CEST` timezone so how can i convert this time(CEST timezone) into milliseconds(CEST timezone)? can you give me an example?

Comment: @ewolden i didn't find a way to convert datetime in specific timezone milliseconds time.

Comment: Working with timezones is tricky. I suggest you use moment and moment timezone to sort out the timezones and get milliseconds from your date strings. See here for usage: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/8Lnoyvm4/24/

Comment: is there any way to pass original timestamp in unix patter in series of highcharts and only display to users that time in specific timezone like `Europe/Berlin` in x axis label? How can i display that converted time in x axis label?

Comment: You can format your labels to whatever you like: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Hi @Fahad Hassan Subzwari, Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867562/create-a-date-object-with-cet-timezone, it can be useful for you.