# How to customize the time zone for a Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

When I look at the log files for my application, the entries are listed in UTC. However, I want the entries to reflect my local timezone. Can you customize the time zone for a Node.js application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615828/how-to-use-timezone-offset-in-nodejs

Comment: @data_henrik - I've tried using moment and moment-timezone and all that comes back shows data in UTC with GMT+0000.

Comment: You can format the way moment and moment-timezone returns data. Here is an example: `var timestamp = moment().tz("America/New_York").format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');`
This will output: "August 18th 2016, 3:30:25 pm" There is more formatting ways described here http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: the problem is I don't know what the time zone is to pass into tz().  I need to get that first, then I can pass that in. How do you get the timezone?

Comment: You can use `moment.tz.names`. The information on the list of timezone names is here:
http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/getting-zone-names/

Comment: @BillWentworth I tried using the moment.tz.names and it does bring back a list of the timezones. Mine always comes back as UTC and everything I try to do to bring back more information, like offset, comes back as 0. I just tried moment().toLocaleString() and this came back-   Mon Aug 22 2016 13:37:17 GMT+0000.  I am in Eastern Time and on Windows 10.  I have the code in my app.js, its not in the html.  I've also tried moment().format("Z") and this comes back with +00:00.