# Insert MySQL date using NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like to insert a MySQL date using NodeJS but it doesn't work.

My new date : `1989-12-31 00:00:00`

After the NodeJS insert : `1989-12-30 23:00:00`

NodeJS inserting :

```
var user = request.body.user;
user.birth = user.birth.year + '-' + user.birth.month + '-' + user.birth.day + ' 00:00:00';
this.userDao.save(user);
```

Result of `new Date()` using Javascript :

```
Thu Dec 08 2016 11:00:15 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
```

If I add one hour of the inserting date it works.

Comment: Please insert mysql error code,insert not working or just this field not inserted?

Comment: May be use moment.js to construct the date from the input values and then use in the `user.birth`

Comment: is there a timezone difference between the machine running your code and the one hosting database?

Comment: Yes I think there is a timezone difference but how to fix it ?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615828/how-to-use-timezone-offset-in-nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [`options.timezone`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/) in Sequelize, otherwise it will use the timezone offset of the database server, which in your case seems to be GMT, or one hour offset from Paris.

> `[options.timezone='+00:00']`
>
> The timezone used when converting a date from the database into a JavaScript date. The timezone is also used to SET TIMEZONE when connecting to the server, to ensure that the result of NOW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and other time related functions have in the right timezone. For best cross platform performance use the format +/-HH:MM. Will also accept string versions of timezones used by moment.js (e.g. 'America/Los_Angeles'); this is useful to capture daylight savings time changes.

**Sequelize connection**

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(db, user, pass, { timezone: 'Europe/Paris' });
```